# Multiple files upload with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, scope

I'm trying to make a script to upload multiple files using ajax, and print them on the screen with a loading circle display.

The script is working for one file, but I have a problem to make it works for multiple files. I guess it a "scope" problem. But my JS knowledge is not that good.

Also, I'm only using standard JS, no jQuery.

Here's the script :

```
var index_div = 0;
var dropper = document.querySelector('#upload');

dropper.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Annule l'interdiction de "drop"
    }, false);

dropper.addEventListener('dragenter', function() {
    dropper.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
});

dropper.addEventListener('dragleave', function() {
    dropper.style.borderStyle = 'dashed';
});

dropper.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dropper.style.borderStyle = 'dashed';
    var files = e.dataTransfer.files,
        filesLen = files.length;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < filesLen ; i++) {
    var NomImage = files[i].name;
    if(files[i] != '')
    {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.setAttribute("class","image_div");
    document.getElementById("upload").appendChild(newDiv); 
    document.getElementsByClassName("image_div")[index_div].innerHTML = '<img id="chargement" src="../includes/chargement.gif"/>';
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', files[i]);
    xhr.open('POST', "./traitement_upload.php", true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName("image_div")[index_div].innerHTML = 
xhr.responseText;
        index_div += 1;
    }
    }
    xhr.send(form);
    }
    }

});
```

Sorry for the sloppy code. If I check the xhr readyState and status during the loop, the first(s) are 1 and 0, then the last one is good.

You can see I'm creating a new div for each uploaded file so I can print a thumbnail in it.

For what I understand, the code is processing while the ajax request is not done yet. The result is I only see the last file I submitted.

If I put a false to the async flag on xhr.open, it works but it doesn't show the loading gif of course.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the code for AJAX functionality in a separate function - otherwise the closure for `xhr.onload` will use the current (at the time of calling) value of `index_div` - most probably the last one from the FOR cycle. Also, `querySelector` returns a collection - even if it finds just a single element, or even if it finds nothing. Also, you should use both `event.dataTransfer` and `event.target` in order to handle both drag/drop and normal clicking.

```
var dropper = document.getElementById('upload');

dropper.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) 
{
  e.preventDefault();
    dropper.style.background = '#eee';
}, false);

dropper.addEventListener('dragenter', function() 
{
  e.preventDefault();
    dropper.style.background = '#eee';
}, false);

dropper.addEventListener('dragleave', function() 
{
  e.preventDefault();
    dropper.style.background = '#fff';
}, false);

dropper.addEventListener('drop', uploadFile, false);
document.getElementById('file_upload').addEventListener('change', uploadFile, false);

function uploadFile(e) 
{
  e.preventDefault();
    dropper.style.background = '#fff';
    dropper.style.borderStyle = 'dashed';
    var files = (e.dataTransfer || e.target).files,
        filesLen = files.length;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < filesLen ; i++) 
    {
        if(files[i] != '')
        {
            var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.setAttribute("class","image_div");
            newDiv.innerHTML = '<img id="chargement" src="../includes/chargement.gif"/>';
            document.getElementById("upload").appendChild(newDiv); 

        doAJAX(newDiv,files[i]);
      }
    }
}

function doAJAX(div,file)
{
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append('file', file);

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
      xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if(window.ActiveXObject)
  {
      xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xhr.open('POST', "./traitement_upload.php", true);
  xhr.onload = function (e) 
  {
    if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
    {
      div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhr.send(form);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer. I already tried this, as it was what I understood from the scope problems I read on the internet, but it is still not working. If I send two different images, there'll be only one image but duplicated.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment. With your code, sometimes it shows the same images (if I send two different, the result will be the same images twice), and other times one image will load and appear, while the other get stuck on the loading gif forever.

Comment: Would be easier if you can provide a CodePen or JSfiddle.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried to create a JSFiddle, here it is, as an example : https://jsfiddle.net/1k9Lvgha/2/  Problem is there's no php backend so it seems to work fine here.

Comment: You could probably try to specify absolute URLs for the PHP backend and for the GIF loader - https://jsfiddle.net/1k9Lvgha/20/